# Issue rendering buttons in the emulator (XML)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, frontend

I have an activity with a bunch of different views and then 2 buttons that are not rendering correctly. I can see where the buttons should appear because when I hover over the section, I can see the selector appearing, but I can't see anything where they should be. I can see the buttons in the layout preview, but not the emulator. All other buttons on that activity, with the same, exact style, are working and rendering as expected.

Below is the code I'm using for the XML layout (the buttons causing the issue are: `@+id/refine` and `@+id/sort`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
        ....
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
       .../>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/refine"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:cornerRadius="30dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sort"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/filter"
        android:theme="@style/MainButtonTheme" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/sort"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:cornerRadius="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/sort"
        android:theme="@style/MainButtonTheme" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        ...
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have checked to see if I accidentally used the wrong colour for the icons, but I definitely haven't.

I also realised that I'm getting an error (this doesn't stop the code from running) - the details of it are below (I have no idea what the issue is):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/emoji2/viewsintegration/EmojiTextViewHelper
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEmojiTextHelper.<init>(AppCompatEmojiTextHelper.java:43)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.getEmojiTextViewHelper(AppCompatTextView.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setFilters(AppCompatTextView.java:219)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1613)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:968)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:93)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:88)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:83)
    at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:61)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:328)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:209)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:608)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:734)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you please tell on which device configuration you are trying to run in emulator?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy i'm running it on a pixel 2, API 28

Comment: Can you copy paste full xml ?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy I have added the code to the question, the 2 buttons that are causing issues are `@+id/refine` and `@+id/sort`. I haven't removed them from the code(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started getting the issue when Android Studio kept suggesting that I use `drawableStart` instead of `drawableLeft`. I didn't know this could be an issue.

After just changing a bunch of things in my code, I finally found that `drawableStart` instead of `drawableLeft` is what caused rendering issues with my buttons so I've now changed back to `drawableLeft` and all works as expected!